# How do I create a WorkplanStep that checks a condition based on the previous process?

Tags: moryx

I need to create a WorkplanStep in a MORYX application that evaluates a condition based on the outcome of the previous activity. Depending on this evaluation, it should produce either “Success” or “Failure”.

I created a new WorkplanStep but don't know how to implement this dependency in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps to create such a WorkplanStep:

Create a Custom WorkplanStep Class:

You’ll need to create a custom class for your WorkplanStep. This class will represent the step in which you want to make the decision.

Here’s a general version of such a class:

```cs
public class CustomConditionStep : WorkplanStepBase
{
    public CustomConditionStep()
    {
        // Initialize your custom step here
        // ...

        // Set the outputs for example
        Name = "Custom Condition Step";
            Outputs = new IConnector[2];
            OutputDescriptions = new[]
            {
                new OutputDescription{Name = "Success", OutputType = OutputType.Success},
                new OutputDescription{Name = "Failure", OutputType = OutputType.Alternative},
            };

    }

    protected override TransitionBase Instantiate(IWorkplanContext context)
    {
        // Create an instance of your custom transition class
        // ...
    }
}
```

Create a Custom Transition Class:

The transition class determines how the step reacts to specific events. Here’s a more detailed version of such a transition class:

```cs
public class CustomConditionTransition : TransitionBase
{
    private IProcess _process;

    public CustomConditionTransition(IProcess process)
    {
        _process = process;
    }

    protected override void InputTokenAdded(object sender, IToken token)
    {
        // Implement your logic here
        // For example, check if a certain condition is met
        // ...

        if (/* Your condition here */)
            PlaceToken(Outputs[0], token); // Success
        else
            PlaceToken(Outputs[1], token); // Failure
    }
}
```

By the way, you need the part with the constructor and the process only if you want to make a decision based on the process.

If you want to add a condition, you can modify the logic in the CustomConditionTransition class.
For example, you can check with an if/else-statement a specific condition and decide whether the process was successful or not.