# How can I make a WorkplanStep parameterizable?

Tags: moryx

I need a WorkplanStep in the MORYX application that can be adjusted with a parameter.

I already have a base class (WorkplanStepBase) that provides general properties and methods for all workplan steps.
Now I would like to create a specific step that is parameterizable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume that you have already created a custom WorkplanStep. If you have any problems with this, you can read how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78112957/how-do-i-create-a-workplanstep-that-checks-a-condition-based-on-the-previous-pro/78113093#78113093).

Now let’s break down the steps, along with code snippets, for making any workplan step parametric:

#### Inherit from ITaskStep:

Every specific workplan step should inherit from the ITaskStep interface. This ensures that all necessary methods and properties for a step are implemented.
Here’s a general example:

```cs
public class MyCustomStep : WorkplanStepBase, ITaskStep<MyCustomStepParameters>
{
    // Implement required properties and methods here
    // ...
}
```

#### Create a parameter class:

Create a separate class to hold the parameters for your workplan step. This parameter class will store the specific settings for the step.
Define properties within this class to represent relevant parameters (e.g., Version, ConnectorType, NumberOfCrimp, etc.).
Here’s a general example:

```cs
public class MyCustomStepParameters: IParameters
{
    public string Parameter1 { get; set; }
    public int Parameter2 { get; set; }
    // Add other relevant parameters

    public MyCustomStepParameters(){}

    public MyCustomStepParameters(string parameter1, int parameter2){
        Parameter1 = parameter1;
        Parameter2 = parameter2;
    }

    public IParameters Bind(IProcess process){
        return this;
    }
}
```

#### Public property parameters:

Inside your specific workplan step, create a public property named Parameters. This property will use the parameter class to store the specific settings for the step.
Here’s a general example:

```cs
public class MyCustomStep : WorkplanStepBase, ITaskStep<MyCustomStepParameters>
{
    public MyCustomStepParameters Parameters { get; set; }
    // Other properties and methods
}
```

#### Query and store parameters in the public constructor:

In the public constructor of your specific workplan step (MyCustomStep), query the values for the parameters and store them in the Parameters property.
Here’s a general example:

```cs
public class MyCustomStep : WorkplanStepBase, ITaskStep<MyCustomStepParameters>
{
    public MyCustomStep(string parameter1, int parameter2)
    {
        Name = "Custom Condition Step";
        Parameters = new MyCustomStepParameters(parameter1, parameter2);
        // Other initialization logic
    }
}
```

#### Private constructor for loading from the database:

If you want to save the workplan step in a database, you can create a private constructor that loads the parameters from the database. This allows you to create predefined steps with saved parameters.

```cs
private MyCustomStep(){
    Name = "Custom Condition Step";
    Parameters = new();
}
```